# Ionic 3 app stops running after installing Background Geolocation Plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic2, ionic3

My Ionic app works just fine. I now want to add the background geolocation plugin.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/

But after installing the plugin:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation
```

When I run the app on my Android device the app crashes immediately after launching with a message 'App has stopped.'

I am not using the plugin yet in the app, I have just installed it. When I uninstall the plugin the app works again.

Any ideas what might be the reason? Or how I can debug this error?

Comment: you have tagged all versions of ionic.. which are you using?

Comment: You should check your device native log.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update your app-script to the latest version. Just run this command.

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

This link is for ionic 2. 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/

may be you are using ionic 1. so that you can use cordova plugin.

try this plugin,

cordova plugin add https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation.git